# Large Data Flow between User and Kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

What is the best way(performance) to have a bi-directional data flow between user-level and kernel-level ?

I understand that you can open a NETLINK socket and transfer the data through there. But, we have to adopt some other user-kernel interaction(system calls, ioctl) for sending control information across. Is this the most efficient way to transfer large amount of data across user-kernel boundary ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to transfer large data from kernel to user-space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4379024/best-way-to-transfer-large-data-from-kernel-to-user-space)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Passing large buffers of data into the kernel driver/thread/whatever is no problem - the kernel has the privilege to read it, no problem.  For returning stuff, the ususal way is to provide the kernel thingy with a sufficiently large user-space buffer, or buffer pool, for it to return data in.  That's how its done for the usual stuff - file/network read/write, for example.

What is the problem, more exactly - do you need to transfer the data to/from kernel level on a different machine?

Rgds,
Martin

Comment: I am trying to create a Application in linux which would act as a Netfilter, but would also be capable of sending larger amount of data across the network. My App. should also be running at the other end. So, I just want my data to be send from local Application user-space buffer to remote Application user-space buffer. Without the additional cost of copy. Is that at all possible ?

Comment: OK, I get it, I think:)  It depends on the data and protocol.  To avoid as much copying as possible, especially with stream-based protocol like TCP, would probably mean your data being presented as a pointer/length array that adresses multiple buffers, ie. exactly as served up by the TCP protocol/stack.  Most apps don't want their data presented like that - they would prefer a nice app-level protocol-data-unit with exactly as many sequential bytes as needed to represent the PDU.  This, I'm afraid, means some copying :((